# Cant Submit Form ( Saas, Paas, Iaas)

Tags: php, jquery, forms

When I try to click on the submit or cancel the form nothing happens.

Here is part of the register_company.php code.

enter code here

```html
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 <!--
 function getArrays() {
  if (validateForm()) {
   loadArray('appcatindex');
   loadArray('targetindindex');
   loadArray('managedservices');
   document.getElementById('company').action = "<?php echo BASE_URL_JCM; ?>/save_company.php";
   document.getElementById('company').submit();
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }
 function loadArray (tcIndex) {
  if (document.getElementById(tcIndex) != null) {
   lnLength = document.getElementById(tcIndex).length;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
  if (tcIndex == 'docindex') {
   textDelim = "";
  } else {
   textDelim = "";
  }
  var lcIDs = "";
  lcDelim = "";
  for (var i=0;i<lnLength;i++) {
   if (document.getElementById(tcIndex).options[i].selected) {
    lcIDs = lcIDs + lcDelim + textDelim + document.getElementById(tcIndex).options[i].value + textDelim;
    lcDelim = ",";
   }
  }
  document.getElementById('a'+tcIndex).value = lcIDs;
 }
 function validateForm() {
  lcReturn = "";
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkText('companyName','Company Name');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkText('firstName','First Name');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkText('contactEmail','Contact E-mail Address');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkSelect('appcatindex','Application Categories');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkSelect('targetindindex','Target Industries');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkSelect('managedservices','Managed Services');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('hardwareTech','Hardware Technology');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('softwareTech','Software Technology');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('serviceSolution','Service Solutions');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('iaassolution','Infrastructure-as-Service(IaaS) Solution');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('paassolution','Platform-as-Service(PaaS) Solution');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('keyDiff','Key Differentiators');
  lcReturn = lcReturn + checkTextArea('sampleCust','Sample Customer Names');
  if (lcReturn != "") {
   lcReturn = lcReturn + "\nPlease correct these fields and resubmit.";
   alert(lcReturn);
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
 function checkTextArea(tcField,tcLabel) {
  lctext = "";
  if (document.getElementById(tcField)) {
   lctest = document.getElementById(tcField).value;
   if (lctest.length > 250) {
    lctext = tcLabel + " is greater than 250 characters ("+lctest.length+" used).\n";
   }
  }
  return lctext;
 }
 function checkSelect(tcField,tcLabel) {
  lctext = "";
  if (document.getElementById(tcField)) {
   lnLength = document.getElementById(tcField).length;
   var lnSelCnt = 0;
   for (var i=0;i<lnLength;i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(tcField).options[i].selected) {
     lnSelCnt++;
    }
   }
   if (tcField!='appcatindex') {
    if (tcField!='targetindindex') {
     if (lnSelCnt > 5) {
      lctext = tcLabel + " has more than 5 options selected ("+lnSelCnt+" selected).\n";
     }
    }
   }
   if (tcField=='appcatindex') {
    if (lnSelCnt > <?php echo $saasAppCoLimit ?>) 
    {
     lctext = tcLabel + " has more than <?php echo $saasAppCoLimit ?> options selected ("+lnSelCnt+" selected).\n";
    }
   }
   if (tcField=='targetindindex' ) {
    if (lnSelCnt > <?php echo $saasIndCoLimit ?>) 
    {
     lctext = tcLabel + " has more than <?php echo $saasIndCoLimit ?> options selected ("+lnSelCnt+" selected).\n";
    }
   }
  }
  return lctext;
 }
 function checkText(tcField,tcLabel) {
  lctext = "";
  if (document.getElementById(tcField)) {
   lctest = document.getElementById(tcField).value;
   if (lctest == "") {
    lctext = tcLabel + " is empty. This field is required.\n";
   }
  }
  return lctext;
 }
 function updateStatus (toOption) {
  lcStatus = toOption.value;
  lcStatus = lcStatus.substring(0,1);
  document.getElementById('status').value = lcStatus;
 }
 -->
    </script>
  
 <div id="divMain" align="center">
 <div id="divContent" align="left">
  <!--img src="<?php echo DOMAIN_URL ?>/343/images/company.jpg" border="0" width="670px" align="top" -->
  <form name='company' id='company' method='post' action=''>
  <!-- h3><?php echo $headtitle ?></h3 -->
   
   <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='getArrays();return false;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='self.close();' />
   <input type="hidden" name="companyid" id="companyid" value="<?php echo $companyid ?>"><input type="hidden" name="querytype" id="querytype" value="<?php echo $querytype ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="profiletype" id="profiletype" value="<?php echo $profiletype ?>"><input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo $status ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="key" id="key" value="<?php echo $key ?>"><input type="hidden" name="createDate" id="createDate" value="<?php echo $createDate ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="updateDate" id="updateDate" value="<?php echo $updateDate ?>"><input type="hidden" name="enablingTech" id="enablingTech" value="<?php echo $enablingTech ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="paas" id="paas" value="<?php echo $paas ?>"><input type="hidden" name="iaas" id="iaas" value="<?php echo $iaas ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="aappcatindex" id="aappcatindex" value=""><input type="hidden" name="atargetindindex" id="atargetindindex" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="amanagedservices" id="amanagedservices" value=""><input type="hidden" name="request_uri" id="request_uri" value="<?php echo $request_uri ?>">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Problem is only related to submit button it does nothing, I googled it but didn't find any posible solution.

Here is the web link http://www.cloudshowplace.com/saas/

Comment: I have added `<form name='company' id='company' method='post' action=''>` in the code, please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer to my problem.

Changed input type "button" to "submit", and it started working like a charm.

`<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='getArrays();return false;' />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='submit' value='Cancel' onclick='self.close();' />`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `</form>` tag but no `<form>` tag.  Something like `<form action="action_page.php" method="post">` should work.  You could also attach javascript actions to the submit button.